# localStorage item conflicting with other localStorage item

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm having an issue when adding the pricing to local storage to other fields. If I set the price for the `beforeNoonNPSlot` to `2`, but I leave the field blank for the `matineeNPSlot` (it should keep whatever price was assigned to it last). Then after I update the changes. The `beforeNoonPrice` is `$2.00` like it should be, but the `matineeNPSlot` is `$NaN`. Also if I set a price for `beforeNoonNPSlot` and a price for `matineeNPSlot` then there is no `NaN` problem.

I want it to be optional to set a price for any field not necessarily all fields without having this issue. How do I prevent this from occurring?

```
function updatePricingFunction() {
    var beforeNoonFieldChange = document.getElementById('beforeNoonNPSlot').value;
    var matineeFieldChange = document.getElementById('matineeNPSlot').value;

    localStorage.setItem('text', beforeNoonFieldChange);
    localStorage.setItem('text1', matineeFieldChange);
 }

function load() {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
    var storedValue1 = localStorage.getItem('text1');

    beforenoonprice = storedValue;
    matineeprice = storedValue1;
    beforeNoonCPSlot.innerHTML = "$" + parseFloat(storedValue).toFixed(2);
    $("#beforeNoonPrice").attr = parseFloat(storedValue).toFixed(2);

    $('#beforeNoonPrice').append("$" + (storedValue * 1).toFixed(2));

    matineeCPSlot.innerHTML = "$" + parseFloat(storedValue1).toFixed(2);
    $("#matineePrice").attr = parseFloat(storedValue1).toFixed(2);

    $('#matineePrice').append("$" + (storedValue1 * 1).toFixed(2));
}



// JavaScript Document
var beforenoonprice = 6.75; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE BEFORE NOON TICKET
var matineeprice = 9.00; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE MATINEE TICKET
var seniorprice = 9.25; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE SENIOR TICKET
var militaryprice = 9.25; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE MILITARY TICKET
var studentdayprice = 8.00; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE STUDENT DAY TICKET
var seniordayprice = 6.75; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE SENIOR DAY TICKET
 var adultprice = 10.75; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE ADULT TICKET
var childprice = 8.00; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE CHILD TICKET
var threeDprice = 3.50; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE REGULAR 3D PRICE
var imaxPrice = 4.50; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE IMAX TICKET
var imax3dPrice = 5.50; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE IMAX 3D TICKET
var output = document.getElementById('output');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting NaN because you're trying to parse an empty string, so either you add a special case to your code where you check if the string is empty before doing formatting (and default to [not set] or something), or you set 0 as a default value, so it can be parsed back and you get $0, makes sense?

Comment: There is a value assigned to the variable getting NaN, but it gets wiped if I try and assign a value to another variable using localstorage

Comment: I might be confused, but you mention that "if you leave the field blank" it should keep the value, but you're not checking that it isn't blank before storing it, so you're effectively storing an empty string, and you don't check when you load it so you're parsing an empty string.

Comment: The values are never blank. There are hardcoded values that are assigned to the variables from the beginning. I edited the code above to show you what I mean. So they should never be empty